# Cocos2D-X v.3.2 CPP-TESTS Can't build under VS2013?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-x v.3.2 under VS2013 getting the following error when compiling:

> error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'cocos2d-x-3.2\cocos2d-x-3.2\tests\cpp-tests\proj.win32\Debug.win32\libcocos2d.lib'

Trying to run the the cpp-tests for win32.
Anyone run into this problem? appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you open the Cpp Tests project from the tests folder: "cocos2d-x\tests\cpp-tests\proj.win32\cpp-tests.vcxproj" or from the build folder: "cocos2d-x\build\cocos2d-win32.vc2012.sln"?

You should be opening the sln... If you are already doing that, could you try a rebuild all?

Kind regards,
Michaël